# Handle Not Found Exceptions in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am trying to invoke sqlplus command from a shell script and then trying to 
check for success/failure using the exit status. However this does not work fo not found scenario. I need to get the exit code of non zero when there are no rows deleted for a given input.

```
sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECTION << EOF
        set heading off pages 0 echo off feedback off 
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
        BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM config where Id_ = '1345';
         IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
           RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
         END IF;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          EXIT 100;
        END;
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

A PL/SQL `EXIT` statement only works inside a `LOOP` . Check this:  [**EXIT Statement**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/exit_statement.htm#LNPLS01318). It is not equivalent to shell's `exit <exitcode>` or SQL* Plus' `exit`.So, your PL/SQL block won't compile at all.

Moreover, you cannot ensure that Shell will capture the same exit code as that of the Oracle's `SQLCODE` for exceptions like `no_data_found`.  Since you already have `WHENEVER SQLERROR`, you may not include the `EXCEPTION` block at all and simply check for non-zero exit code.

```
sqlplus -s $DB_CONNECTION << EOF
        set heading off pages 0 echo off feedback off 
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
        BEGIN 
         DELETE FROM config where Id_ = '1345';
          IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            RAISE NO_DATA_FOUND;
          END IF;
        END;
EOF 
exit_code=$?
if [ $exit_code != 0 ]
then
  echo "No rows deleted for the given input"
fi
```

Comment: Missing `END;` of block

Comment: @kfinity : Thank you!